# Nested array processing using map to produce a string result

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested

Given the following array (nested), I'm unsure how to loop through these nested arrays using map to produce the below result.

```
const qry = [
  {
    qryNm: "A",
    qryResult: "",
    qryWhere: [
        {
            qryReqs: [
                {
                    col: "name",
                    op: "=",
                    colVal: "tom"
                },
                {
                    col: "country",
                    op: "=",
                    colVal: "germany"
                }   
            ]
        },
        {
            qryReqs: [
                {
                    col: "name",
                    op: "=",
                    colVal: "sally"
                },
                {
                    col: "country",
                    op: "=",
                    colVal: "italy"
                }   
            ]
        }        
    ]
  },
  {
    qryNm: "B",
    qryResult: "",
    qryWhere: [
        {
            qryReqs: [
                {
                    col: "name",
                    op: "=",
                    colVal: "kirk"
                },
                {
                    col: "country",
                    op: "=",
                    colVal: "sweeden"
                }   
            ]
        },
        {
            qryReqs: [
                {
                    col: "name",
                    op: "=",
                    colVal: "grace"
                },
                {
                    col: "country",
                    op: "=",
                    colVal: "usa"
                }   
            ]
        }        
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to loop through the above array and produce the following result:

```
(name = 'tom' and
 country = 'germany')
or
(name = 'sally' and
 country = 'italy')
```

and assign this value to `qryResult` within the qry array, for that `qryNm`, i.e.:

```
qryResult = "(name = 'tom' and country = 'germany') or (name = 'sally' and country = 'italy')";
```

Obviously, this `qryResult` will need to be processed for every array element within the `qry` array.

So for every `qryReqs` within the array `qryWhere`, break this as an "OR" condition.

Having the three level of arrays, I'm unsure how to achieve my result.

I realise that I need to use:

```
qry.map((q, i) => (
  // unsure from here
))
```

Any help/guidance would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break the problem down into parts. First, you need to turn the below object (`req`):

```js
{col: "name", op: "=", colVal: "sally"}
```

into the string:

```js
name = 'sally'
```

This can be done by using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (or string concatenation) and by accessing the `col`,  `op` and `colVal` properties from your object:

```js
`${req.col} ${req.op} '${req.colVal}'`
```

Now that you can convert the individual objects into strings you can map your innermost (`qryReqs`) array using the above template literal:

```js
qryReqs: [ 
  { col: "name", op: "=", colVal: "sally" }, 
  { col: "country", op: "=", colVal: "italy" } 
]
```

The mapping function for this would look something like:

```js
qryReqs.map(req => `${req.col} ${req.op} '${req.colVal}'`)
```

This produces an array of strings:

```js
["name = 'sally'", "country = 'italy'"]
```

In your output, you want this to be in the form of: `(string[0] and string[1] and string[2] and ... and string[n])`. We can [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the strings in this array using `.join(' and ')` to get a string, and then wrap that string in parenthesis `()`:

```js
`(${qryReqs.map(req => `${req.col} ${req.op} '${req.colVal}'`).join(' and ')})`
```

Doing this gives us a string joined with "and"s for each inner object wrapped in parenthesis:

```js
"(name = 'sally' and country = 'italy')"
```

Since we want to perform the above mapping operation on all of your objects inside of `qryWhere`, we can map `qryWhere` and apply the above template literal + join() logic to each object:

```js
qryWhere.map(
  ({qryReqs}) => `(${qryReqs.map(req => `${req.col} ${req.op} '${req.colVal}'`).join(' and ')})`
)
```

Doing the above gives us:

```js
["(name = 'tom' and country = 'germany')", "(name = 'sally' and country = 'italy')"]
```

With this result, we need to join them together with an "or" clauses to match your output, which can be done by joining the above array of results with `.join(" or ")`:

```js
qryWhere.map(
  ({qryReqs}) => `(${qryReqs.map(req => `${req.col} ${req.op} '${req.colVal}'`).join(' and ')})`
).join(' or ')
```

You can then perform an outer `.map()` on your `qry` array to perform this conversion for all objects in your array:

```js
const qry = [{ qryNm: "A", qryWhere: [{ qryReqs: [{ col: "name", op: "=", colVal: "tom" }, { col: "country", op: "=", colVal: "germany" } ] }, { qryReqs: [{ col: "name", op: "=", colVal: "sally" }, { col: "country", op: "=", colVal: "italy" } ] } ] }];

const results = qry.map(({qryWhere}) => qryWhere.map(
  ({qryReqs}) => `(${qryReqs.map(req => `${req.col} ${req.op} '${req.colVal}'`).join(' and ')})`
).join(' or '));
const [res] = results; // if you want to extract the first result

console.log(results);
console.log(res);
```

If you want to add an additional property `qryResult` to your objects, this can be done by creating a new object `{}` in your map callback, and then using the spread syntax `...` to copy all the (enumerable own) keys from the current object to the new object. You can then add the new `qryResult` to the new object with the value of the above mapping:

```js
const qry = [{ qryNm: "A", qryWhere: [{ qryReqs: [{ col: "name", op: "=", colVal: "tom" }, { col: "country", op: "=", colVal: "germany" } ] }, { qryReqs: [{ col: "name", op: "=", colVal: "sally" }, { col: "country", op: "=", colVal: "italy" } ] } ] }];

const result = qry.map((qryObj) => ({
  ...qryObj,
  qryResult: qryObj.qryWhere.map(
    ({qryReqs}) => `(${qryReqs.map(req => `${req.col} ${req.op} '${req.colVal}'`).join(' and ')})`
  ).join(' or ')
}));

console.log(result);
console.log(result[0].qryResult);
```

Comment: As per comment above: After thinking further about the result, decided that it would more beneficial to  store it as part of the `qry` array, within `qryResult`. Unsure how this can be achieved as part of your solution as there will be multiple `qry` array elements.

Comment: @ArthurJ I have updated my answer so that it adds an additional property `qryResult`

Comment: Nick, I updated my scenario above to include two queries, `qryNm A` and `qryNm B` so apologies for not including another query within my example but I basically require now is two separate `qryResult` values on a per `qryNm` basis. Using your second solution, is there a means of just pulling out the `qryResult` for each query without hardcoding the array index of `result[0]` and `result[1]` as part of your solution?

Comment: @ArthurJS How do you want to pull out the query though if you don't explicitly reference it? You can loop over your results array: `results.forEach(query => console.log(query.qryResult));` that will log all the qryResults, but I'm not sure if that is what you want? Or do you want to be able to do something like `results.A.qryResult`, so in that case `results` is an object?

Comment: All good Nick - managed to achieve what I was after based on your second solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to achieve a similar result

```js
const qry = [{
  qryNm: 'A',
  qryWhere: [{
      qryReqs: [{
          col: 'name',
          op: '=',
          colVal: 'tom',
        },
        {
          col: 'country',
          op: '=',
          colVal: 'germany',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      qryReqs: [{
          col: 'name',
          op: '=',
          colVal: 'sally',
        },
        {
          col: 'country',
          op: '=',
          colVal: 'italy',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}, ]

const result = qry
  .map(obj1 =>
    obj1.qryWhere
    .map(
      obj2 =>
      `( name = '${obj2.qryReqs[0].colVal}' and country = '${obj2.qryReqs[1].colVal}' )`
    )
    .join(' or ')
  )
  .join(' or ')

console.log(result)
```

Comment: After thinking further about the result, decided that it would more beneficial to  store it as part of the `qry` array, within `qryResult`. Unsure how this can be achieved as part of your solution as there will be multiple `qry` array elements.